# Is it possible to observe changes in presentingViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Is there any equivalent in Swift to `RACObserve(self, presentingViewController)`?

Or any other why to imitate this behaviour?

- My issue is that I want to be notified whenever a view controller is "hidden" by another view controller. In objc what I'd do is to check if `self.presentingViewController` is `nil`.
- Note that in this scenario there's no knowledge of which view controller is presented, so it's impossible to notify from within its `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: You can get notified which viewController is top .. but can you tell little detail what you want to know actually ?

Comment: @EkramulHoque How can I get notified which view controller is on top? And what other details are you missing?

Comment: opss sorry i'm giving an answer now .

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your question: you need to to know which view controller is presented now and you need notification in`viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear`.

So we can get this in several way.

The simple way is:

1. Get information of which is the top ViewController right now.

2.Call this method in your `viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear`
Like this :

Get Which is The Top ViewController

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {

        if var topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {

            while let presentedViewController = topVC.presentedViewController {
                topVC = presentedViewController
                return topVC
            }
            return topVC
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Call in viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        if let top = getTopViewController() {
            print("topView Controller name \(top.title)")
            top.view.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Hey, thanks but you misunderstood the question. I need to be notified when the presenting view controller changes, _i.e._ push-based, not the ability to test which view controller is currently presented. If `presentingViewController` was KVO-Complaint I'd obverse changes on it.

Comment: Opps .Actually what you want notified can you give an example ??